# Can anyone call transferFrom function of a ERC20 token?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

For the following code:

```
contract ERC20Token {
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value);
}

contract MyContract {
    function myFunction(address tokenAddr) {
      ERC20Token tok = ERC20Token(tokenAddr);
      tok.transferFrom(_owner, _recipient, 100);
    }
}
```

Can anyone call transferFrom function of a ERC20 token?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can call any function they want, so in a literal sense, yes, anyone can call it.

But in an ERC20-compliant token contract, that transaction will revert unless the caller has been authorized to transfer enough tokens from the `from` address.

Comment: so how do you authorize the caller? or how does the caller know it's authorized?

Comment: Perhaps https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/30/writing-an-erc20-token-contract/ will help. [ERC20 itself](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) should also make this clear.